# Jquery default word is not deleting upon triggering dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi Fellow stackoverflow.

I'm working on a jQuery for dropdown function.
My motive is , when user A head towards a page.

There will be a dropdown option code as below :

```
<select id="preference">
<option value="select">select</option>
<option value="beaches">beaches</option>
<option value="museums">museums</option>
<option value="mountains">mountains</option>
```

Then i set the static as the first dropdown which is "Select" . So i set a div class called result.default. As it will show.

```
<div class="result.default" data-preference="select" data-style="chill">beaches and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="fast-paced">beaches and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches2" data-style="both">beaches and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="chill">museums and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums4" data-style="fast-paced">museums and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums5" data-style="both">museums and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="chill">mountains and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains7" data-style="fast-paced">mountains and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains8" data-style="both">mountains and both</div>
```

This is the css :

```
.result {display:none;}
.result.active {display:block;}
.result.default {display:block;}
```

This is the jQuery function :

```
  $('#preference').on('change', function(){
    // set reference to select elements
    var preference = $('#preference');
    $('.result.default').removeClass('default');

    // check if user has made a selection on both dropdowns
    if ( preference.prop('selectedIndex') >= 1 ) {
        // remove active class from current active div element
        $('.result.active').removeClass('active');


        // get all result divs, and filter for matching data attributes
        $('.result').filter('[data-preference="' + preference.val() + '"]').addClass('active');            
    }
});
```

This is the jSFiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/EFM9b/42/
```

So , my motive is when user select option 2 , beaches. I want to remove the active.default. But it's being static when even i choose option 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multiple class in HTML, you should separe them with a space, not a dot. So your first result div should be :

```
<div class="result default" data-preference="select" data-style="chill">beaches and chill</div>
```

And everything will work :)

You were one dot close to the solution !

Answer (score 0):

**JSFIDDLE :** http://jsfiddle.net/EFM9b/43/

Add an active class on the default option and then remove the default class.

You don't need the default if you the active class. So by putting active class to your default option you can have what you want.

```
.result {display:none;}
.result.active {display:block;}




$('#preference').on('change', function(){
  // set reference to select elements
  var preference = $('#preference');
  $('.result.active').removeClass('active');

  // get all result divs, and filter for matching data attributes
  $('.result').filter('[data-preference="' + preference.val() + '"]').addClass('active');   
});



<select id="preference">
  <option value="select">select</option>
  <option value="beaches">beaches</option>
  <option value="museums">museums</option>
  <option value="mountains">mountains</option>
</select> 
<div class="result active" data-preference="select" data-style="chill">beaches and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="fast-paced">beaches and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches2" data-style="both">beaches and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="chill">museums and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums4" data-style="fast-paced">museums and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums5" data-style="both">museums and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="chill">mountains and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains7" data-style="fast-paced">mountains and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains8" data-style="both">mountains and both</div>
```